# Extending type with an optional type

Tags: typescript

I have a base type

```
type BaseProps = {
  foo: boolean;
  bar?: string;
};
```

This base type can be extended with 2 additional types:

```
type WithOkButton = {
  useOkButton: boolean;
  onOK(): void;
};

type WithCancelButton = {
  useCancelButton: boolean;
  onCancel(): void;
}
```

My goal is to have a type which has `baseProps` and all the combinations of additional types:

- none of the additional types
- both additional types
- only `WithOkButton`
- only `WithCancelButton`

I can achieve my goal like this, but I don't like it. Can you please help me to find a better way?

```
type BaseWithOK = BaseProps & WithOkButton;

type BaseWithCancel = BaseProps & WithCancelButton;

type BaseWithBoth = BaseProps & WithOkButton & WithCancelButton;

type ResultType = BaseProps | BaseWithOK | BaseWithCancel | BaseWithBoth;
```

#### Update

Here is how the code will look like if I need all the combinations for three buttons

```
type BaseProps = {
  foo: boolean;
  bar?: string;
};

type A = {
  useA: boolean;
  onClickA(): void;
};

type B = {
  useB: boolean;
  onClickB(): void;
};

type C = {
  useC: boolean;
  onClickC(): void;
};

type BasePropsWithA = A & BaseProps
type BasePropsWithB = B & BaseProps
type BasePropsWithC = C & BaseProps
type BasePropsWithAB = A & B & BaseProps
type BasePropsWithBC = B & C & BaseProps
type BasePropsWithAC = A & C & BaseProps
type BasePropsWithABC = A & B & C & BaseProps

type Props = BaseProps | BasePropsWithA | BasePropsWithB | BasePropsWithC
| BasePropsWithAB | BasePropsWithBC | BasePropsWithAC | BasePropsWithABC;
```

Comment: So... what *does* it look like when you have 3 or 4 buttons? I would like some way to see the resulting type so I can get a feel for what you want.

Comment: Which types are the ones you need to use? Only Props?

Comment: I need the final type `Props`

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found a solution. It can be done with help of an utility type like this:

```
type Optional<T> = T | {};
```

It allows to make all the possible combinations of additional types in one line of code:

```
type Props = BaseProps & Optional<WithOkButton> & Optional<WithCancelButton>;
```

So I suggest to solve the initial issue like this:

```
type Optional<T> = T | {};

type BaseProps = {
  foo: boolean;
  bar?: string;
};

type WithOkButton = {
  useOkButton: boolean;
  onOK(): void;
};

type WithCancelButton = {
  useCancelButton: boolean;
  onCancel(): void;
};

type Props = BaseProps & Optional<WithOkButton> & Optional<WithCancelButton>;
```

What do you think?

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Ndrn6W)

Comment: Mm seems to work. I should stop reaching for the gun first for these kinds of problems...

Answer (score 0):

According to official typescript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it is a recommended method.

Comment: TY for your answer Usama Arslan. This syntax is fine if I have only two buttons (which gives 4 possible combinations). But the problem is that this number will exponentially increase: I would need 9 for three buttons, 16 for four buttons, 25 for 5 and etc. 

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want combinations of the extensions all intersected with the base, so here I have a type that generates combinations from a tuple adapted from [this JS impl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7025):

```
type CombinationsImpl<Active extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, Rest extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, A extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> =
    [Active["length"] extends 0 ? true : false, Rest["length"] extends 0 ? true : false] extends [true, true]
        ? A
        : Rest["length"] extends 0
            ? [...A, Active]
            : Rest extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
                ? [...CombinationsImpl<[...Active, Head], Tail, A>, ...CombinationsImpl<Active, Tail, A>]
                : never

type Combinations<A extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = CombinationsImpl<[], A, []>;
```

Then all we need to do is "loop" over the tuples with distributive conditional types and do the intersecting:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type CreateProps<Base, Exts extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> =
    Combinations<Exts>[number] extends infer U extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        ? U extends U
            ? Base & UnionToIntersection<U[number]>
            : never
        : never
```

Keep in mind that for larger inputs, this may slow down your TSServer (thing that provides autocomplete/intellisense).

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBRv4N)